# Какой тренажёр для обучения машинописи ребёнка выбрать?

Tags: письменность

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ к ВОПРОСУ

Скоро С. исполнится 6 лет. Уже сейчас ясно, что он научиться свободно читать на русском языке ещё до поступления в школу. Поэтому вопрос, вынесенный в заголовок, стал для меня актуальным.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Если С. научится печатать тексты на клавиатуре [компьютера], тогда С. сможет пользоваться компьютерными  средствами контроля за орфографией и пунктуацией, например, при проверке своих сочинений типа "Свиристели прилетели, посидели-посидели, взмыли вверх и улетели."

Если С. научится печатать тексты на клавиатуре [компьютера], тогда С. сможет редактировать свои тексты, не оставляя "грязи".

По моему мнению, сначала ребёнка следует научить печатать тексты, а затем, если это необходимо, ребёнка следует научить писать тексты (например, гусиным пером).

Comment: Тут возникает такой парадокс... Если С. научится молотить по клв вслепую со скоростью 200 знаков в минуту, но не будет иметь глубоких, сознательных навыков правильного письма (орфографической зоркости), С. придётся останавливаться через слово и пользоваться "компьютерными средствами контроля" - и вся эта скорость пойдёт коту под хвост.

Comment: Поздравляю с возникновением парадокса "тут".

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял из вопроса, кто кого и чему обучать будет. Но мнение имею:

1) Не надо сажать шестилетнего за компьютер. Я бы определил здесь подходящий возраст как для обучения игре на духовых инструментах, не раньше.

2) Тренажёр обучения машинописи состоит из двух существенных частей: бумажка со схемой клавиатуры (каждой букве соответствует номер пальца - поищите в интернетах, там есть) и бумажка (тряпка, салфетка...), закрывающая собственно клавиатуру от глаз. То есть при наборе текста вы должны смотреть не на клавиатуру, а на бумажку со схемой, и на ощупь нажимать нужную клавишу нужным пальцем.

Состав текстов (бывают всякие хитрые наборы слов - для каждого ряда на клв отдельно) имеет здесь очень мало значения; главное - количество времени (и не подглядывать!).

Comment: Лучше бы хорошо и грамотно писать от руки учили, а молотить по клаве он и сам научится.

Comment: Мой опыт говорит, что не научится :-). Большинство окружающих меня взрослых (коллег, родственников) так и не научились. Ну, кроме тех, кого я силой заставил.

Answer (score 0):

Когда закончился третий день обучения С. машинописи, он напечатал вслепую несколько слов:  "да", "ода", "вода", "овод", "довод", "вывод", "вдова", "жало", "жажда", "дылда", "водовод". (31.01.2014)

У С. появилась мышечная память на воспроизведение букв Ф, Ы, В, А, П, Р, О, Л, Д, Ж. Вместе с тем, он ещё поглядывает на прочие буквы (К, Е, Г, Н, М, И, Т) и знак Ь, которые осваивались на этой неделе (07.02.2014)

На этой неделе С. начал печатать слова с буквами Ч, С, Б, Ц, У, Ш, Щ. (14.02.2014).

На этой неделе С. познакомился с последними буквенными клавишами (21.02.2014).

На этой неделе С. начал печатать квазипредложения типа "форварда радовала жара", в которых нет ни прописных букв, ни знаков препинания (28.02.2014).

Comment: Галактино, ну и ..ле? Когда моему ребёнку исполнилось 6, она ни..а не умела печатать на клавиатуре. У Вас первый ребёнок? Пусть делает, что хочет.

Comment: См. http://nekin.info/e21.htm